# Drupal Wiris integration

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, mathml

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.wiris.com/en/news/plugins/informal-instructions-plugin-drupal) to install the Wiris plugin on a new installation of Drupal.

Once the installation was complete and I clicked on the Wiris icon to begin adding a formula, the popup window does NOT load and I get the following error in the console area:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '/DrupalQuiz/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/' in a call to 'postMessage'.
at http://*.*.*.*/DrupalQuiz/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/core/core.js:19:22
```

The code causing the problem is as follows:

```
e.source.postMessage(postVariable, _wrs_conf_path);
```

I'm at a loss how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Sorry buddy, still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete fix but I was able to get it working locally by replacing `_wrs_conf_path` with the base path of my dev box. `_wrs_conf_path` was evaluating to a relative path to the plugins folder.

`if (typeof(e.source) != 'undefined') { 
   e.source.postMessage(postVariable, _wrs_conf_path);
 }`

with

`if (typeof(e.source) != 'undefined') {
   e.source.postMessage(postVariable, _wrs_currentPath);
}`

in the /sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/core/core.js file.

Edit: I replaced `_wrs_conf_path` with one of their internal variables `_wrs_currentPath` and that seemed to fix the issue.